# Javascript - How to know the type of the response in Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

**How to know the type of the response in Fetch API?**

In XMLHttpRequest, there's the [`responseType` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) which indicates the type of the returned response's body (json, text, blob, etc.). While in the [Fetch API response](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Response), even though there are useful methods to parse its body (`json()`, `text()`, `blob()`, etc.), I still didn't find any property like the XMLHttpRequest's `responseType` property, to indicate what's the type of the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can check the headers of the response for the content-type as below:

```
response.headers.get("content-type")
```

Comment: relying on this is naive. the server can return a wrong content-type

Answer (score 6):

I think *orangespark* is right. The `content-type` response header *should* be used.

1. If `content-type` header is missing or invalid. It is OK to top futher processing the response:

   > When **extract** a MIME type **returns failure** or a MIME type whose **essence is incorrect** for a given format, **treat this as a fatal error**. Existing web platform features have **not always** followed this pattern, which has been a major source of security vulnerabilities in those features over the years. In contrast, a MIME type’s parameters can typically be safely ignored.
   > https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#content-type-header
2. Since there are many valid media types, some libs *lazy probe* the `Content-Type` header: `response.headers.get("content-type").includes('json')` for `json` existence, before `response.json()` is called.

   > There are 1500+ [Media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) registered with the [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) which can be set as the Content-Type for a request.
3. If `content-type` is not set (or forgotten to set). A [default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) of `text/plain` might be set by the server, which would 'break' your response handling.
4. If `content-type` is not one of the accepted media types, or `body` does not match the `content-type` ...

   Request:

   > accept: text/html, image/avif;q=0.9, image/apng;q=0.8

   Response (bad):

   > content-type: application/json

   ... you could make your app more failsafe and [`clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) the `response` before reading the `body`. So you can still return JSON e.g. an error with the `text` response that could not be parsed as JSON.

   ```js
   const response2 = response.clone();
   let data;
   try {
       data = await response.json(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON
   } catch (e) {
       text = await response2.text(); // response clone can still read as a fallback
       data = {
           error: e.message,
           invalidJson: text
       };
   }
   ```
5. You could use [`response.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) as an alternative for `response.text()`, `response.json()`,...

   The returned `Blob` has a property [`blob.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type) that holds the `content-type` header value.

   Here are some samples, how to handle those blobs:

   1. Blob SVG: `image/svg+xml` content
   2. Blob HTML: `text/html` content
   3. Blob JSON `application/json` content
   4. Blob JSON `application/octet-stream` content
   5. Blob Bad `???/???` content

```js
(async() => {
  const c = document.body;

  imageBlob = () => {
    const svg = `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="80" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="#FF0066" d="M31.5,-16.8C35.9,3.2,31,19.6,16.3,32.8C1.5,46,-23.2,55.9,-36.6,46.9C-50.1,38,-52.3,10.1,-44.3,-14.8C-36.4,-39.8,-18.2,-61.9,-2.3,-61.2C13.6,-60.4,27.2,-36.8,31.5,-16.8Z" transform="translate(100 100)" /></svg>`;
    return new Blob(
      [svg], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml'
      }
    );
  }

  htmlBlob = () => {
    return new Blob(
      ['<span>HTML <b style="color: red">blob</b></span>'], {
        type: 'text/html'
      }
    );
  }

  jsonBlob = type => {
    const json = {
      a: 1,
      b: {
        c: 'val'
      }
    }
    const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
    return new Blob([jsonStr], {
      type
    });
  }

  // Blob instances you might get from: await response.blob()
  // blob.type is set from 'Content-Type' header of its response
  const blobs = [
    imageBlob(),                          // 1
    htmlBlob(),                           // 2
    jsonBlob('application/json'),         // 3
    jsonBlob('application/octet-stream'), // 4
    jsonBlob('???/???')                   // 5
  ]

  for (const [i, b] of Object.entries(blobs)) {
    c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('h3'), {
      textContent: `${1+parseInt(i)}. ${b.type}:`
    })) //      b.type === 'Content-Type'━━┛

    if (b.type.startsWith('text/html')) { // 1
      const text = await b.text();
      c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {
        innerHTML: text
      }));
    } else if (b.type.startsWith('image/')) { // 2
      c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {
        src: URL.createObjectURL(b)
      }));
    } else if (b.type.startsWith('application/json')) { // 3
      c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('pre'), {
        textContent: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(await b.text()), null, ' ')
      }));
    } else if (b.type.startsWith('application/octet-stream')) { // 4
      c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
        textContent: 'download json',
        href: URL.createObjectURL(b),
        download: 'data.json'
      }));
    } else { // 5
        // .... create a clone Response from blob
        // -> response2 = new Response(await response1.blob())
        const response2 = new Response(b);
        const b2 = await response2.blob(); // .json() .text(),...
        const text2 = await b2.text(); 
        console.log('blob2', text2, b2.type);

        // Blogs are  b === b2
        const text = await b.text();
        console.log('blob1', text, b.type);
        
        console.log('blob2 === blob1', text === text2); // true
    }
  }
  
      c.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('h3'), {
      innerHTML: `&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;`
    }))
})()
```

Comment: tldr: `const blob = await response.blob(); const type = blob.type`